# three.js - identify point on tube circumference and rotate from that point

Tags: three.js

Below is my code for the scene of tube geometry. I've loaded 200 co-ordinates as JSON data from external file.

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>3d Model using HTML5 and three.js</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: #f0f0f0;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #info {
                    color:#000;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px; width: 100%;
            padding: 5px;

            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>              
        <div id="info">         
            WASD-move, RF-up/down, QE-roll, mouse-look around, mouse left/right click- zoom-in/out 
        </div>            
        <script src="three.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Curve.js" type="text/javascript"></script>             
        <script src="Stats.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Detector.js" type="text/javascript"></script>      
        <script src="path.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script>

        // variables
        var container, stats;

        var camera, scene, renderer, controls;

        var text, plane, tube, tubeMesh, parent;

        var targetRotation = 0;
        var targetRotationOnMouseDown = 0;

        var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0; var radius = 6371;
        var mouseXOnMouseDown = 0;

        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;   

        var clock = new THREE.Clock();

        function plotPath()
        {                                           
            var obj = getPath();
            var segments = 60;
            var closed = false;
            var debug = true;
            var radiusSegments = 12;
            var tube;
            var points = [];
            var x=0,y=0,z=0;
            var extrudePath;

            for(var i=0; i<obj.path.length; i++)
            {                               
                console.log(obj.path[i].point);
                points.push(obj.path[i].point);                                                                                 
            }

            extrudePath = new THREE.SplineCurve3(points);               
            tube = new THREE.TubeGeometry(extrudePath, segments, 2, radiusSegments, closed, debug);         

            tubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(tube ,new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                color: 0x000000, side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                opacity: 0.5, transparent: true, wireframe: true}));    

            if ( tube.debug ) tubeMesh.add( tube.debug );

            scene.add( tubeMesh );

        } 

        init();                             
        animate();

        function init(){
            // container
            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );         

            // scene            
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2( 0xcccccc, 0.002 );

            // renderer         
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: false } );
            renderer.setClearColor( scene.fog.color, 1 );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            // camera   
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );

            // light
            light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
            light.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
            scene.add( light );

            light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0x002288 );
            light.position.set( -1, -1, -1 );
            scene.add( light );

            light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x555555 );
            scene.add( light );

            // CONTROLS
            controls = new THREE.RollControls( camera );
            controls.movementSpeed = 50;
            controls.lookSpeed = 3;
            controls.constrainVertical = [ -0.5, 0.5 ];         

            // Grid
            geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
            geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( - 500, 0, 0 ) );
            geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( 500, 0, 0 ) );

            for ( var i = 0; i <= 20; i ++ ) {

                line = new THREE.Line( geometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000, opacity: 0.2 } ) );
                line.position.z = ( i * 50 ) - 500;
                scene.add( line );

                line = new THREE.Line( geometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000, opacity: 0.2 } ) );
                line.position.x = ( i * 50 ) - 500;
                line.rotation.y = 90 * Math.PI / 180;
                scene.add( line );
            }                   

            // projector
            projector = new THREE.Projector();

            plotPath();

            // stats
            stats = new Stats();
            stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
            stats.domElement.style.zIndex = 100;
            container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

            // events           
            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
        }

        function onWindowResize() {
            windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        }

        function animate() {            
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();
            update();
        }

        function update(){
            controls.update(clock.getDelta());
            stats.update();
        }       

        function render() {         
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
        </script>        
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I identify a point on tube circumference and how to rotate a tube from that point ?

[image: Screenshot of 3d model]

Comment: In your loop, you are reassigning the mesh and parent variables over and over. Also, can you please rephrase your question? It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I've updated the details as per your suggestion.-@WestLangley

Comment: In your loop, you are reassigning the `extrudePath` varibale over and over, and it is not declared. What are the `dynamic` properties and `dirtyVertices` for? Do you need them? What is `tube.debug`. What is `camera.left` used for?

Comment: Ok I made changes. I read about `dynamic` and `dirtyVertices` that these properties are required if the geometry is being updated. `tube.debug` shows an axis helper at each point and I've simply pasted code for window resize event.

Comment: In your loop, you are still reassigning the `extrudePath` variable over and over. What is `parent` for? Why did you add `tubeMesh` as a child of `parent` and also as a child of `scene`? What is the code in you window resize callback actually doing? Can you remove some of it?

Comment: Updated code as per your suggestion and thanks a lot for pointing out my coding mistakes.- @WestLangley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OrbitControls`, for example, has a property `target` which is both the center of rotation and the `camera` look-at position.

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
```

You can change the center of rotation of the camera using picking.

```
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var vector = new THREE.Vector3( 
        ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, 
        - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 
        0.5 );

    projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );
    var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

    var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( objects );    

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

        controls.target.copy( intersects[0].point );

    }

}
```

EDIT: Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eVkgs/30/

three.js r.65

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works but `OrbitControls` makes camera movement difficult. Using `RollControls` I can easily traverse the whole tube geometry. As I said there are certain values on the circumference of tube and for easy movement user can spin the tube by clicking on a point to show different values. What changes should I make to implement such functionality ? - @WestLangley

Comment: I think I have done all I can for you. You will only really learn this if you figure it out yourself. I was glad to help you get started. Good luck.

Comment: Ok sure and thanks once again. Any suggestions would be great help.-@WestLangley