# three.js - rotate particular part of geometry

Tags: three.js

I've created a tube geometry with following function.

```
function plotPath()
        {                                           
            var obj = getPath();
            var segments = 60;
            var closed = false;
            var debug = false;
            var radiusSegments = 12;
            var tube;
            var points = [];
            var x=0,y=0,z=0;            

            for(var i=0; i<obj.path.length; i++)
            {                               
                console.log(obj.path[i].point);
                points.push(obj.path[i].point);                                                                                 
            }

            extrudePath = new THREE.SplineCurve3(points);
            tube = new THREE.TubeGeometry(extrudePath, segments, 10, radiusSegments, closed, debug);                                

            tubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(tube ,new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                color: 0x000000, side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                opacity: 0.5, transparent: false, wireframe: true}));

            tubeMesh.add(new THREE.AxisHelper());
            var v = new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0).normalize();           
            tubeMesh.applyMatrix(matrix.makeRotationAxis(v, 0));
            tubeMesh.applyMatrix(matrix.makeTranslation(-500,0,0));

            if ( tube.debug ) tubeMesh.add( tube.debug );                                   
            scene.add(tubeMesh);
            objects.push(tubeMesh);                                         
        }
```

Here `extrudePath` is built with points passed as argument to `THREE.SplineCurve3(points)`. Points are stored in external javascript file as JSON format.
In this tube geometry I can rotate/spin the initial part of it. When I zoom out and try to rotate/spin the middle or end part of tube, I can't. The rotation is weird.

How can I rotate/spin particular part of tube geometry ? Do I need to break it in some small parts to make rotation smooth ? Or is it possible to add `THREE.AxisHelper` at each point to make rotation/spin look easier ?

[image: Default view of Tube]
[image: Zoom out view of Tube]

Comment: Any suggestions to implement such functionality ?

Comment: I've already posted a question on rotating a portion of tube geometry. Any suggestions or solution ?-@WestLangley

Comment: Any suggestions to implement such functionality ?- @WestLangley

Comment: at least you got a badge for this question