# Click on a mesh and rotate it so that face is on the floor

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a mesh object on a floor and based on a click I want to rotate that mesh so it is on the floor.  I'm able to get the click and select the mesh but how can I get the face to figure out how to rotate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say without code example, but probably you're looking for:

1. Use [Raycaster intersectObject](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster.intersectObject) for determining both mesh and
   face you're clicking at;
2. Determine face rotation by looking into [face normal vector](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Face3.normal) . Note that you must call `Geometry.computeFaceNormals()` before using it if you build your mesh manually
3. Rotate mesh around face center to the angle, which can be calculated from face normal vector. The simplest approach to rotate around Vector3 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746011/three-js-how-do-i-rotate-a-cylinder-around-a-specific-point/12749570#12749570)

Hope it will help