# Update radius of TubeGeometry at runtime

Tags: three.js

How to dynamically change the radius of a mesh based on the TubeGeometry at runtime.

Here is how I create the mesh:

```
var points = new THREE.SplineCurve3([
  new THREE.Vector3(source.x, source.y, source.z),
  new THREE.Vector3(target.x, target.y, target.z)
]);
var geometry = new THREE.TubeGeometry(points, 10, 1, 10, false, false);
geometry.dynamic = true;
var material =  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0x0000cc});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

And here how I try to update the radius of the tube:

```
var geometry = mesh.geometry;
geometry.radius = 200;
geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
mesh.updateMatrix();
```

Unfortunately it does not update the tube radius. How is it done correctly? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `radius` parameter is only used during construction of the geometry. Changing it will have no effect.

You could change `mesh.scale`, but that will likely not work as you would like in your case due to the spline curve. ( It would work for a `CyllinderGeometry`. )

three.js r.58

Comment: Indeed, the radius of a tube can't be easily changed by scaling it. I am using a cylinder now (as I only connect two points) using [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316127/three-js-line-vector-to-cylinder) (reference if someone else got stuck here).