# Create ArrowHelper with correct rotation

Tags: three.js

How do I create an ArrowHelper in Three.js (r58) with correct rotation?

```
var point1 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
var point2 = new THREE.Vector3(10, 10, 10);
var direction = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(point1, point2);
var arrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper(direction.normalize(), point1);
console.log(arrow.rotation);
```

I always end up with with `Object {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}` for the arrow rotation. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just like to add that I am trying something like [this (see answer there)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316127/three-js-line-vector-to-cylinder), but it seems that rotation is not set any more on ArrayHelper.

Comment: var direction = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(**point2**, **point1**);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ArrowHelper` uses quaternions to specify it's orientation.

If you do this:

```
var rotation = new THREE.Euler().setFromQuaternion( arrow.quaternion );
```

you will see an equivalent orientation expressed in Euler angles, although in r.59, `arrow.rotation` is now automatically updated, so you will no longer see zeros.

EDIT: answer updated to three.js r.59

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly. Also added an answer to the older question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316127/three-js-line-vector-to-cylinder/16348610#16348610).